# broken screen windows 7 laptop connect to open network

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, display, thinkpad

I currently have two laptops.

Laptop A - Lenovo thinkpad OS: Windows 7 laptop screen broken

Laptop B - lenovo thinkpad OS: Windows 8.1

Laptop A's monitor has damaged and does not function. However HDMI, VSA PORTS damaged in windows 7.

I have installed teamviewer, if i can connect open access wifi to windows 7 and open teamviewer, I can access files inside windows 7 through teamviewer

Any possible suggestions to connect windows 7 to internet

Answer (score 1):

since they are both laptops... i would recommend a hardline connection which would allow you to set up the wifi connection via teamviewer.  once the wifi is set up, you can configured it to automatically connect to the WIFI connection u set up, you should be okay to revert bec to WIFI.1 issue you may run into is I believe teamviewer only has unattended support available on the premium version, but i could be wrong.

dictated but not read-